# What GPS geographic coordinate system is this?

Tags: gps

I received a couple of gps data on animal movements from a research paper but was unable to recognize the format and map it.

Any idea what format these GPS coordinates are?

The GPS locations should be in Singapore.

```
N 01’24 487, E 102 46.950
N 01’ 24 422, E 103 46.831
N 01’ 24 600, E 103 46.805
N 01’ 24 558, E 103 46.821
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like hemisphere, degrees, minutes, and thousandths of minutes:

```
N 01’24 487, E 102 46.950
N 01’ 24 422, E 103 46.831
N 01’ 24 600, E 103 46.805
N 01’ 24 558, E 103 46.821
```

but with a space missing on the first line (possibly a transcription error).

If you want to convert to decimal degrees, this little function (written in R) might help:

```
dms = function(d,m,th){d+(m/60)+((th/1000)/60)}
```

which shows your first points Northing is:

```
> dms(1,24,487)
[1] 1.408117
```

ie 1.408117 degrees north, in (probably) the WGS84 EPSG:4326 coordinate system, which is the usual default for GPS coordinates unless your GPS has been set to record in a different coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

WGS84 (EPSG:4326) is standard for GPS

> The Global Positioning System uses the World Geodetic System (WGS84) as its reference coordinate system.
>
> It comprises of a reference ellipsoid, a standard coordinate system, altitude data and a geoid.
>
> See https://gisgeography.com/wgs84-world-geodetic-system/